# Warehouse routes between each started workorder in production order

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I'm working with odoo11 community version and currently I have some problem.

This is my exmplanation of problem:

In company I have many workcenters, and for each workcenter:
1) I want to create separate warehouse for each workcenter
or
2) Just 1 warehouse but different storage areas for each workcenter

(currently I made second option) and each workcenter have their own operation type: Production

Now my problem started, There are manufacturing orders and each manufacturing order have few workorders, And I want to do something that when some workorder is started then products are moved to this workcenter's warehouse/storage area and they are there untill next workorders using different workcenter starting then product are moved to next workcenter warehouse/storage area.

I can only set that after creating new sale order production order is sent to first Workcenter storage area and he is ther untill all workorders in production order are finished, I don't know how to trigger move routes between workcenters storage areas. for products that are still in production stage

Can I do this from odoo GUI, or maybe I need to do this somewhere in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found my answer, which is that to accomplish what I wanted I need to use Manufacturing with Multi levell Bill of material, it working in way that theoretically 3 steps manufacturing order is divided into 3 single manufacture orders with 1 step each, and for example 2 and 3 prodcution order which before were 2 and 3 step are using as components to produce product that are finished in previous step which now is individual order.